# SQL Query Select from 1 table and return data based on 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp

I'm working on a SQL query where I have data stored in table `r.` Based on the columns of `give` or `receive`, I need to store the data in a temp table to then store in a new table.

Essentially, the data is pulling from 3 tables and the end goal is to get the binary code for an image and store to display in `.net`

I'm trying to figure out the multi select at this time

So `give` or `receive` in `r` equals `Username` in `S`, display all the data that pertains and get the image if `employee` equals `employee`

I've tried a good amount of code and I feel like an `OR` would do the trick but it doesn't seem to.

Thanks for any help you may provide.

```
SELECT  
    r.id, r.give, r.[receive], r.[type], r.[description], r.isApproved, 
    r.photoGive, r.photoReceive 
INTO
    #temp2 
FROM 
    Intranet.dbo.Recgonize r

SELECT s.Employee, s.Username 
INTO #temp3 
FROM Vision7.dbo.SEUser s

SELECT p.Photo, p.Employee 
INTO #temp4 
FROM Vision7.dbo.EMPhoto p

SELECT * 
FROM #temp2 AS a
INNER JOIN #temp3 b ON a.give = b.Username 
INNER JOIN #temp4 c ON b.Employee = c.Employee

DROP TABLE #temp2
DROP TABLE #temp3
DROP TABLE #temp4
```

Comment: This does get the correct pull for "give". If I put an OR in for receive = username, it doesn't yield any new results

Comment: desired result is in the question. 
sample data - https://ibb.co/qjCyrcR

Comment: based on the columns, I need to query give and receive compared to username that then ties to employee and selects photo from 3 tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using temporary tables for this?  These just make code harder to debug and maintain, more expensive to run, and more complicated to understand.

`JOIN`s will work without temporary tables.  But you do have to additional logic to get the give and receive values in separate columns, so more `JOIN`s are necessary:

```
SELECT r.id, r.give, r.[receive], r.[type], r.[description], 
       r.isApproved, r.photoGive, r.photoReceive,
       pg.Photo as give_photo, pg.Employee as give_employee,
       pr.Photo as receive_photo, pr.Employee as receive_employee
FROM Intranet.dbo.Recognize r LEFT JOIN
     Vision7.dbo.SEUser sg
     ON r.give = sg.Username LEFT JOIN
     Vision7.dbo.SEUser sr
     ON r.receive = sr.Username LEFT JOIN
     Vision7.dbo.EMPhoto pg
     ON sg.Employee = pg.Employee LEFT JOIN
     Vision7.dbo.EMPhoto pr
     ON sr.Employee = pr.Employee
```

Comment: temp table method I thought made sense in for selecting all and then comparing the data to get the proper select. I tried an execute of the above and this is the result. I'm looking to see the why. "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near 'Vision7'."

Answer (score 0):

You may want try following:

```
-- Include only required columns select rather than "*"

SELECT * 
FROM #temp2 AS a
INNER JOIN #temp3 b ON a.give = b.Username 
INNER JOIN #temp3 b2 ON a.receive = b2.Username 
INNER JOIN #temp4 c ON b.Employee = c.Employee
INNER JOIN #temp4 c2 ON b2.Employee = c2.Employee
```

or

```
-- Include only required columns in select rather than "*"

SELECT * 
FROM 
        (select r.id, r.give as UserName, r.[type], r.[description], r.isApproved, r.photoGive  from #temp2
         union
         select r.id, r.[receive], r.[type], r.[description], r.isApproved, r.photoReceive from #temp2
        ) AS a
INNER JOIN #temp3 b ON a.UserName = b.Username 
INNER JOIN #temp4 c ON b.Employee = c.Employee
```

If temp tables are NOT used for necessary need by application, same logic can work with actual tables, just replace #Temp2, #Temp3, #Temp4 with appropriate table names.

Comment: thanks, for your first scenario, I'll still need to use the selects I have correct and then essentially, what it's doing is creating 2 different temp tables based off of give and receive?

Comment: No, it simply join one temp table twice (1. for `give`, 2. for `receive`). it would also, work if you just replace temp tables with actual tables.

Comment: thanks - the photo column is an image one - not by my design but a 3rd party app. I get "he data type image cannot be used as an operand to the UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operators because it is not comparable." when executing. I'll research the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try with a single script as below-

```
SELECT a.id, 
       a.give, 
       a.[receive], 
       a.[type], 
       a.[description], 
       a.isApproved, 
       a.photoGive, 
       a.photoReceive, 
       b.Employee, 
       b.Username, 
       c.Photo, 
       c.Employee
FROM Intranet.dbo.Recgonize A
     INNER JOIN Vision7.dbo.SEUser B ON a.give = b.Username
     INNER JOIN Vision7.dbo.EMPhoto C ON b.Employee = c.Employee;
```

Comment: thanks - using that, it still pulls back just give results     its much cleaner though.

Comment: would it make more sense if i did 2 queries on the .net side    one for give and then one for receive and store the results in a temp table then pass it through to a actual sql table?

Comment: What benefit of using a temp table? I am confused.

Comment: I thought it made sense to store the selects in there to join but that is obviously not the best way to go after seeing some comments. Your method is very good and is almost what I'm looking for.     if it can get receive as well as the link for username in SEUser it would complete it.    That's why I was thinking of 2 calls.

Comment: Add sample data from different tables and also your expected output from them. This will help to reach the goal.

Comment: here is a photo of the sample data.   expected output would be that based on give or receive equaled to username based on employee from seuser and emphoto get the photo and tie it to give or receive      https://ibb.co/qjCyrcR